# Flex / grid layout. Need advice how to lay out blocks properly using Flex of Grid CSS model

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

**Hi, community!** 
I need advice on, is it possible to achieve the following card structure (without additional wrappers)?

***Desired behavior:***
the first row should have the 3 cards, the second - 2 cards, the 3-rd - 3 cards and go on...
I've attached a simple example for the first 2 rows for a better understanding of the problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.list .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.list .item .card {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the space between the cards to be equal or the cards to be equal width ? because you can't both

Comment: the space between the cards, like in the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set static width for cards, you can try something like that:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: grid;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
}

.list .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.list .item:nth-child(5n - 1) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.list .item:nth-child(5n) {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.list .item:nth-child(5n - 1),
.list .item:nth-child(5n) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}


.list .item .card {
  width: 200px; /* static width */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `width: 100%;` on the cards ?

Comment: because the cards won't be of equal width and I guess that's not what he wants.

Comment: I've tried something similar with flex, but the distance between the cards in the 2-nd row is different than in the 1-st row. 
So, unfortunately, this approach doesn't suit desired layout(

Comment: Oh i see, @IhorLavs i think you should be more specific your question

Comment: @doğukan wow, it looks great. I need to try this approach in my app. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could make the 2 items you want in one row slightly bigger so it pushes the 3rd item into the next row. the div's are not exacly the same size(.6 % bigger than the 3 items in the row above/below) but it's hard to notice

```css
.list .item:nth-child(5n - 1){
  width: 33.6%;
}
.list .item:nth-child(5n) {
  width: 33.6%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.list .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.list .item .card {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="card"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tiny margin to two elements and you can have the same width and also the same distance between elements:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list .item .card {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.list .item:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  margin-left:1%
}

.list .item:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  margin-right:1%
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```